# Enable transparent panel with wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, transparency

**What i want to create is:**

- having a background image in a panel
- having a second panel in the foreground with an splitter on the left side
  -->the splitter should not affect the size of the background image and the right side where there is no splitter should be transparent so you can see the background image

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <wx/splitter.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class BackgroundPanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    BackgroundPanel(wxWindow* parent, const wxString& imagePath)
        : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
    {
        wxImage image;
        image.LoadFile(imagePath, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
        backgroundBitmap = wxBitmap(image);
    }

    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
    {
        wxPaintDC dc(this);
        dc.DrawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
    }

private:
    wxBitmap backgroundBitmap;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(BackgroundPanel, wxPanel)
    EVT_PAINT(BackgroundPanel::OnPaint)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class ForegroundPanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    ForegroundPanel(wxWindow* parent)
        : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
    {
        SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(*wxBLUE));
        SetMinSize(wxSize(150, 150));
    }
};

class TransparentPanel : public wxPanel {
public:
    TransparentPanel(wxWindow* parent, const wxString& imagePath)
        : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
    {

        wxImage image;
        image.LoadFile(imagePath, wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
        transparentBitmap = wxBitmap(image);
        transparentBitmap.UseAlpha();
    }

    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
    {
        wxPaintDC dc(this);
        dc.DrawBitmap(transparentBitmap, 0, 0);
    }

private:
    wxBitmap transparentBitmap;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TransparentPanel, wxPanel)
    EVT_PAINT(TransparentPanel::OnPaint)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MyFrame()
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Xenturys KSP Editor", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600))
    {
        SetMinSize(wxSize(400, 300));

        BackgroundPanel* backgroundPanel = new BackgroundPanel(this, "Anypath\\Image.png");

        wxSplitterWindow* splitter = new wxSplitterWindow(backgroundPanel, wxID_ANY);

        ForegroundPanel* foregroundPanel = new ForegroundPanel(splitter);
        TransparentPanel* transparentPanel = new TransparentPanel(splitter, "Anypath\\Transparent.png");

        splitter->SplitVertically(foregroundPanel, transparentPanel);

        wxBoxSizer* hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        hbox->Add(splitter, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

        backgroundPanel->SetSizer(hbox);
    }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        // Register the PNG image handler
        wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);

        MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
        frame->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

In this approach i tried assigning a transparent picture, but this does also not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Search for "transparent" inside [wx docs](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html)

Comment: You would use `SetTransparent` in your "TransparentPanel" constructor. `UseAlpha` in a bitmap (if supported by the OS) will show the background of the window where the bitmap is drawn.

Comment: As you may see i tried useAlpha but i seems i'm doing something wrong, could you may please have a look and elaborate what i could do to fix it? Thank you very much, so glad for your response. :)

Comment: @Studying, what do you see on the screen? What OS do you use and what wx version?